# Vertically floating social icon buttons with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there a way to create sticky (floating), vertical icon buttons for a page using jQuery or other library? The buttons are centered vertically on the left or the right of the screen as a bar, and remain in the same location when the user scrolls. Here's an example of a library that generates the buttons for Wordpress: http://www.clickonf5.org/cute-profiles

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a cross-browser implementation of the CSS `position:fixed` property.

There's the [JQuery UI Position Plugin](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/Position) and other implementations like [this](http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/).